# Joomla : Putting the submenus somewhere else

Tags: menu, joomla

I'm using the default menu in Joomla. So, I have the following structure :

```
Menu 1
--Submenu1
--Submenu2
--Submenu3


Menu 2
--Submenu1
--Submenu2
--Submenu3
```

The problem is that I want to include the submenus horizontally on the top of the page instead of displaying them just below the root menu. For example, if I click on "Menu2" :

```
              Submenu1     Submenu2
Menu1
Menu2(selected)
```

Is it possible ?

Than you.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific, quite hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to remove the submenus from the vertical main menu et put them horizontally in each (concerned) page ?

Comment: Just to make it clear: you want to remove the sub menu items from the main menu, and show the submenu-items on its parent-menu-item-pages only?

Comment: Yes : I want to print them horizontally in the content page being displayed .

Answer (score 0):

There you go: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_submenu

I havent done this in a while, but using seperate menu modules is a pretty flexible solution. I'm not quite sure, but I think there are also extensions that do what your want. Either way, the above link should help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know how to create the submenus (as stated above), but how can I import the submenus in the content pages ?

Comment: You have to create sub menu modules and publish them only on the appropriate pages.

Comment: Will it detect then the current page I'm on and then publish the corresponding submenus ?

Comment: Yes, as outlined in the article, the submenu will be shown only on pages you specify. You can set the exact pages where you want your module to be displayed in the "menu assignment" section in the module parameters.